# What is the relationship of MSAL to Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm interested in implementing SSO for an organisation using Azure Active Directory and ASP.NET Framework 4.x.

After studying the Microsoft docs I came across the advice to use MSAL (Microsoft Authentication Library) and also a code sample on GitHub [here](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet). The code sample is referenced by this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-webapp).

According to NuGet [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/) is the MSAL library. But the code sample above makes no reference to that library. As can be seen in the packages.config file [here](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/blob/master/AppModelv2-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/packages.config).

The packages.config file and the article make reference to other libraries:

```
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
```

So what is the relationship of these packages to MSAL?

Answer (score 3):

The packages you mention are used by an ASP.NET MVC app to authenticate users with the OpenID Connect + Cookies combo.
They are used to authenticate the user in the app.
In the context of back-end Web apps, MSAL deals with token acquisition, not user authentication.
So if your app needs to call e.g. MS Graph API, you can use MSAL to get the access token for that, after the OpenID Connect package has finished authenticating the user and received an authorization code.
MSAL can request for tokens, and handles token caching and token refresh for you.

Answer (score 2):

### Microsoft Authentication Library

MSAL is a library that can be used to acquire and manage tokens from **Microsoft identity platform endpoint** in order to authenticate users and access some protected APIs (e.g. Graph API).

### Microsoft.Owin.Security.* (ASP.NET MVC)

These are packages that you can use in ASP.NET MVC applications. `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect` is a package which contains OWIN middleware which accepts and validates incoming access tokens.

So:

- if you want to sign users into your ASP.NET MVC application using AzureAD, use `Microsoft.Owin.Securit.OpenIdConnect`. You can check following [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp).
- if you want to acquire and manage tokens on behalf of some user, use `MSAL`